# I am using the gLTF addon, how do I make my node group glTF Metallic Roughness exactly the same as my Diffuse BSDF

Tags: materials, node-editor, gltf

*When using the **Diffuse BSDF***
[image]

*When using the **glTF Metallic Roughness***
[image]

As you can tell the colour of the cubes looks different from each other. Additionally when using the glTF Metallic Roughness, you can see it is reflecting this white colour and I don't want that.

How do I make the glTF Metallic Roughness **Exactly** the same as Diffuse BSDF so that the object looks exactly the same?

(I installed this addon from this place https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter/tree/master/docs)

Answer (score 2):

They're different shading models; it may not be possible to exactly match one with the other and vice versa. If you're creating a model for export into some 3D engine, you should try importing both and verify that it looks correct there, as ultimately the engine will determine how it looks.

In the future the glTF Blender Exporter will work with the Principled BSDF node, and then you won't need a special addon glTF PBR node like this.